# Comparison question with implicit 再 zài?

Tags: grammar, characters, difference, sentence-structure, syntax

I just started learning chinese and I came across this dialogue from a lesson:

> A: Pínɡuǒzěnme mài ? 苹果怎么卖? *How much are the apples?*
>
> B: Sìkuài. 四块. *4 Yuan*.
>
> A: Yǒudiǎnr ɡuì. **Kěyǐpiányi yìdiǎnr mɑ?** 有点儿贵。**可以便宜一点儿吗？** *A bit expensive. Can you make it cheaper?*
>
> B: Sān kuài wǔ. 三块五. *3,5 Yuan*.
>
> A: **Zài piányi yìdiǎnr, hǎo mɑ? 再便宜一点儿，好吗？** *Can you make it cheaper?*
>
> B: Hǎo, sān kuài. 好，三块。*Ok, 3 Yuan.*

I'm wondering about the differences between:

1. Kěyǐpiányi yìdiǎnr mɑ? 可以便宜一点儿吗？
2. Zài piányi yìdiǎnr, hǎo mɑ? 再便宜一点儿，好吗？

In the lesson they said 再 zài can mean *more* in chinese, so I understand literally 2. as *More cheap a little bit, ok?*. So it is clear the speaker wants the product to be cheaper than it is now. However I do not completely understand 1., as literally would mean *Can it be cheap a little bit?*, missing the comparison specifier.

**Question:** What's the underlying grammar structure in 1.? Does actually have the word 再 zài implicit, like

> Kěyǐ(zài)piányi yìdiǎnr mɑ? 可以(再)便宜一点儿吗？

so it really becomes a "comparison" question such as 2.? Or does this mean comparisons in chinese are a little bit more flexible than other languages (like English), where you always need to specify them in some way?

I asked a chinese friend about this and he said usually 1. can be asked just single time and then if you want to ask for still a cheaper product you use 2. any number of times. Does this mean they are not completely equivalent as I expected?

Comment: 便宜一点儿 can be comparison, as in '比起那个，这个便宜一点儿' (this is cheaper compared with that). And it also means as an idiom 'to lower the price'. 再 is like asking for a lower price than the current price, so you can use it any number of times and even from the very beginning.

Comment: IMO that sentence is better translated as "can you make it cheaper even more" instead of "can you make it more cheap".

Comment: "可以便宜一点儿吗？"(Can (you) make it cheaper?) "再便宜一点儿，好吗？(Can (you) make it cheaper again, is it OK?)" 再 means again.

Comment: @000 In the lesson they said 再 can also mean "more" and gave some examples such as 再大一点儿 (bigger) or 再高一点儿 (taller), which is why I thought 再 couldn't mean "again" in this sentence...

Comment: @Puco4 Maybe they means [this](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000009505)(sense 4) but I cannot verify whether or not it can be interpreted this way in this component(再便宜一点). I think it more probably means again.

Comment: @000 ah, I don't know enough chinese to understand that :S I understand the interpretation you give, but then there is this second interpretation of "more" such as 再大一点儿 as bigger or 再高一点儿 as taller. It also appears in [this dictionary](https://dictionary.reverso.net/chinese-english/%E5%86%8D). Because it is really similar to the other examples and they explained it in the same lesson, I thought "可以便宜一点儿吗?" was just the same with 再 being implicit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"可以便宜吗？" = "Can it be cheap?"

"可以便宜一点儿吗？" = "Can it be cheaper?"

"可以(更)便宜一点儿吗？" = "Can it be cheaper (more)?" -- *compare to **cheaper** price*

可以(再)便宜一点儿吗？ = Can it be cheaper (again) -- *repeat 'the action **be** cheaper*

It may be easier to understand with different phrasing:

> "可以便宜一点儿吗？" = "Can you lower the price?"
>
> "可以(更)便宜一点儿吗？" = "Can you lower the price (more)?"
>
> "可以(再)便宜一点儿吗？" = "Can you lower the price (again)?"

You can repeat the same phrase as many time as you want until you get the lowest price you can get.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the first sentence is 可以便宜.

可以 is "can", 便宜 is something like V-ing form, a noun.

再 means '**again**', so it is not 'more', not a 'comparison'.

可以便宜一点儿吗？
再便宜一点儿，好吗？

Those literally means:

Can it be cheap?

Can it be cheap **again**?

Comment: But [in this dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese-english/%E5%86%8D) they say it can also mean *more*...